# Watching a property for changes in typescript / Vue3 and still be be able to run this.<methods>

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have a control (a slide bar to adjust values) that works just fine in normal situations. But when state of the parent changes, it needs to get the updated value.

So in the parent I have:

```
<ValueScroller
  :model-value="wheel.splitAngle"
  :minMax="{
    min: state.hslMode ? 0.2, : 0,
    max: state.hslMode ? 0.95 : 1,
  }"
  label="Split Angle"
  v-on:change="change"
  name="wheelSplitAngle"
  :showValue="true"
  :useVw="true"
/>
```

In this, model-value works correctly, it changes in the control when it is passed. But min-max never updates.

```
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    minMax: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
    {other props omitted for brevity}
  },
  watch: {
    maxMin(newVal) {
      this.state.min = newVal.min;
      this.state.max = newVal.max;
      console.log("wuz here 2");
      this.init();
    },
    modelValue(newVal) {
      this.state.currentValue = newVal;
      console.log("wuz here");
      this.init();
    },
  },
  mounted(): void {
    this.init();
  },
}
methods: {
  init(): void {
    <stuff here that needs to have the current 
     values of model-value and especially minMax>
  }
},
```

I have seen code examples where the watch is defined in setup(props) but this isn't very useful because "this" isn't defined, so I can't run init(). When the watches are defined this way I have done here, they never get hit, I have logged them and nothing happens. With them in setup() they get hit, but "this" isn't defined so it isn't useful to me. The watch for modelValue seems unnecessary, it just works. I am using computed values for the various things that make the control work, but they still use the original state rather than the currently passed minMax. I only need the passed minMax to update one way, it is never modified by the control so the behavior I want doesn't seem inappropriate to me.

The only workaround I've had so far is to use v-if and have separate sets of controls with different minMax settings, which seems like an utter kludge to me. Another workaround would be to inject the data, but it just makes a mess on the parent page for such a small thing, and inject is more than what I need anyway, I just need one-way data, inject is two-way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are watching `maxMin`, but it should be `minMax`:

```
  watch: {
    maxMin(newVal) { // <--------- should be minMax
      ...
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Moritz Ringler was right, the watch works when the variable is spelled correctly. MaxMin sounds better than MinMax, I feel kinda embarrassed about such a silly error. But at least we now have an answer for this that is written in typescript.

The watch for ModelValue isn't necessary and never gets hit because the control re-renders when it is changed. This may be due to templates that use different controls in in different states, they ARE being re-rendered. (I put a console.log in setup() to confirm this.

So now when the minMax changes, init() runs and uses the new value.

Comment: Oh, if my answer helped you, please consider leaving an upvode and/or mark it as the accepted answer. It is a bit silly, but it is how the site works

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did that.